# Логическая ошибка, которую не могу выявить в Unity3d.

Tags: unity3d

Я пытаюсь заставить заспауненные снаряды лететь во врагов, но вместо этого летает моя башня.
Атаку пытаюсь реализовать тут: (void Attack()- сам спаун и атака, а остальное чисто формальности)

```
`public class Attack_Tower_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> enemys;//список враго(тут всё правильно)
    Vector2 spawnpoint;
    float distance;
    GameObject tower;
    //public Shell shell_1;
    //public Shell shell_2;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] shells = new GameObject[1];
    GameObject image;
    void Start()
    {
        spawnpoint = transform.position;
        image = GameObject.Find("Image");
        /*if(image!= null)
        {
            image.SetActive(false);
        }*/
        tower = gameObject;
        enemys = GetComponent<Towers>().enemys;
        InvokeRepeating("Attack", 1f, 0.1f);
    }
    void Attack()
    {
        if (enemys.Count > 0 /*&& tower.GetComponent<Towers>().TimerAttack <= 0f*/)
        {
 //           image.SetActive(true);
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 90f));
            //distance = Vector3.Distance(enemys[0].transform.position, transform.position);

            for (int i = 0; i < enemys.Count; i++)
            {
                if (enemys.Count > 0 && enemys[i] != null)
                {
                Instantiate(shells[0], spawnpoint, transform.rotation);
                Instantiate(shells[1], spawnpoint, transform.rotation);

                    float distance = Vector2.Distance(enemys[i].transform.position, transform.position);
                    //if (distance <= 5f)
                    shells[0].transform.LookAt(enemys[i].transform);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(shells[0].transform.position, enemys[i].transform.position,
                        (Random.Range(6F, 10F) * distance) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                    shells[1].transform.LookAt(enemys[i].transform);
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(shells[1].transform.position, enemys[i].transform.position,
                        (Random.Range(6F, 10F) * distance) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результаты интерполяции вы назначаете в трансформ пушки, а не пули.
transform получаемый просто в монобехе, а не у другого объекта возвращает трансформ объекта, на котором монобех висит.

Comment: Но появилась новая ошибка: снаряды ни в какую не хотят долетать до цели.

Comment: @НОЧНЫЕБЕСЕДЫ, вы уверены, что правильно используете линейную интерполяцию? Например, результатом Lerp(0, 10, 0.5f) будет 5. А вы используете в качестве первого значения не хешированную позицию пушки, а позицию снаряда.

Comment: Я поменял её на MoveTowards, но, увы, эффект не поменялся.

Comment: К тому же,  позиция башни в качестве первого аргумента тоже ни на что не повлияла.

Comment: @НОЧНЫЕБЕСЕДЫ, если честно, я не совсем понимаю, как у вас вообще движение объекта реализовано. Это самонаводящиеся ракеты? Почему они летят между двумя объектами, а не из точки вылета прямо? о.о к тому же трудно понять по какой причине "снаряды не хотят долетать". Создайте новый вопрос с подробным описанием текущей проблемы - сообщество попробует разобраться.